# SSG in Layout of Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch data in footer of my site with SSG so that It's become SEO friendly.

According to Documentation we cannot use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps currently
[Nextjs layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#:%7E:text=Inside%20your%20layout%2C%20you%20can%20fetch%20data%20on%20the%20client%2Dside%20using%20useEffect%20or%20a%20library%20like%20SWR.%20Because%20this%20file%20is%20not%20a%20Page%2C%20you%20cannot%20use%20getStaticProps%20or%20getServerSideProps%20currently.)

Is there any way to do server side call in footer  ?

I tried to do with code with nextjs docx but still I can't resolve it . I can pass data as pageProps from page but I think it have to do in every page .